# How can I calculate the mixing enthalpy related with the viscosity of binary alloy?

Tags: thermodynamics, viscosity

Which expression of the mixing enthalpy can be used to calculate the viscosities of binary alloys?

Comment: Who says the enthalpy of mixing bears any relationship to the viscosity?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple model that relates the enthalpy of mixing with viscosity of a binary mixture is the Moelwyn-Hughes (MH) model.
Be aware, that the literature states slightly different equations for the MH-Model, mainly differing in the way the enthalpy of mixture is normalized.

However, the original source:
Moelwyn-Hughes, E. A., 1964, Physical Chemistry, 2nd edition (Pergamon Press),
p. 793